# How to get city and state using BING map api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps

How to get state, city or zip when using Bing api. I can get Latitude and longitude in return but I'm not sure how to get City and State using zipcode or by city and state get zipcode. Or based on Latitude and longitude get city, state and zipcode. Does anyone know how to accomplish it? Thank you in advance for working examples

Answer (score 0):

use this api
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/{0},{1}/{2}?mapSize={3},{4}{5}&mapVersion=v1&key=